# ORMLite: Support for Views?

Tags: java, ormlite

I am just researching ORMLite a bit and it looks pretty nice. One question I have is whether there is any support specific to SQL Views?
How to select from a view?
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect not.  What is a SQL view?  What are you trying to achieve.  This seems like a question for the user list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ormlite-user

Comment: now,I have a view in database,I want to select data from this view,i don't konw how to do.i have see this:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/Kf3-oVUEO6A ,but this link's question don't solve.

Comment: You can select from a view, just like any table, but you can't create views.

Comment: https://github.com/robotoworks/mechanoid supports Views and a lot of other usefull stuff. A beta fork is available for Android Studio https://github.com/justeat/mickeydb

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create the view and then treat it like a table. It worked perfectly for me.